# Jest(React) syntax error, configuration problem after the run of jest coomand

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I have use these packages in the package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "jest-extended": "^3.0.1",
    "jest-junit": "^14.0.0",
  }
```

Also have configuration for jest like this

```
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupTests.js",
      "./node_modules/jest-enzyme/lib/index.js",
      "jest-extended"
    ],
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-junit"
  }
```

Setup.tests.js file is in the root folder with content

**

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

**

When I run **jest --runInBand --ci --verbose true** I have got

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

```
Details:

/setupTests.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { configure } from 'enzyme';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I have create .babelrc file in the root of folder and add

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```